# Не привязываются данные к модели

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, asp.net-web-api

Когда данные приходят на `WebApi` контроллер, модель приходит, но в ней все строки `null`. Распознаются только `enum`ы.

Попробовал посмотреть есть ли данные в `var data = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();` и оказалось что они есть.

```
// POST: api/Events
    public void PostSome(NewEventVm eventVm)
    {
        var data = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    }
```

**Typescript**

```
submitEventForm(): void {
    debugger;
    this.event.Image = this.image;
    let postData = { eventVm: this.event };
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = JSON.stringify(postData);
    var a = this.http.post("/EventsModuleApi/Events/PostSome", body, options).toPromise(this.result);
};
```

В чём может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как насчет добавить код, а?

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: Не оборачивайте `this.event` в объект. Попробуйте так `let postData = this.event;` вместо `let postData = { eventVm: this.event };`